# Caching a fully dynamic website

Tags: php, linux, caching

I made a dynamic site that has over 20,000 pages and once a page is created there is no need to update it for at-least one month or even a year. So I'm caching every page when it is first created and then delivering it from a static `html` page

I'm running a php script (whole CMS is on PHP) `if (file_exists($filename))` to first search for the filename from the url in **cache-files** directory and if it matches then deliver it otherwise generate the page and cache it for latter use. Though it is dynamic but still my url does not contain `?&=`, I'm doing this by `-` and breaking it into array.

What I want to know is will it create any problem to search for a file from that huge directory?

I saw a few Q/A like [this](http://www.frank4dd.com/howto/various/maxfiles-per-dir.htm) where it says that there should not be problem with number of files I can store on directory with `ext2 or ext3` (I guess my server has ext3) file system but the speed of creating a new file will decrease rapidly after there are files over 20-30,000.

Currently I'm on a shared host and I must cache files. My host a soft limit of 100,000 files in my whole box which is good enough so far.

Can someone please give me any better idea about how to cache the site.

Comment: windows has an issue with large number of files per directory... doesn't sound like you are referring to windows hosting though.

Comment: Perhaps you can meet half way between caching and dynamic pages if only the content of the page is slightly changing and the HTML isn't -- just store the HTML template on the disk and the content in a database.

Comment: @ReyGonzales: The point of staticifying the content is that HTML pages are served (much, **MUCH**) faster than PHP pages, especially in very high traffic sites. So if you have a static version of a file, you cna serve that instead of querying the database each time etc.

Comment: @Dave I have no intention to move to Windows but I said that for just information as ext3 too may have some kind of effects.

Comment: Supposedly is_file() [http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php] is slightly faster than file_exists().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't place all of the 20K files in a single directory.

Divide them into directories (by letter, for example), so you access:

```
a/apple-pie-recipe
j/john-doe-for-presidency
```

etc.

That would allow you to place more files with less constraints on the file-system, which would increase the speed. (since the FS doesn't need to figure out where your file is in the directory along with other 20k files, it needs to look in about a hundred)

Comment: Your suggestion is great and I'll do this but for just information is PHP fast enough (it will be faster than creating a new I know) to search for a file from 20,000 files in directory?

Comment: @Anuj: I don't know, is it fast enough for you? Try it and see.

Answer (score 0):

> there should not be problem with number of files I can store on directory with ext2 or ext3

That's rather an old document - there are 2 big differences between ext2 and ext3 - journalling is one, the other is H-TREE indexing of directories (which reduces the impact of storing lots of files in the same directory). While it's trivial to add journalling to an ext2 filesystem and mount it as ext3, this does not give the benefits of dir_index - this requires a full fsck.

Regardless of the filesystem, using a nested directory structure makes the system a lot more manageable and scalable - and avoids performance problems on older filesystems.

(I'm doing 3 other things since I started writing this and see someone else has suggested something similar - however Madara's approach doesn't give an evenly balanced tree, OTOH having a semantic path may be more desirable)

e.g.

```
define('GEN_BASE_PATH','/var/data/cache-failes');
define('GEN_LEVELS', 2);

function gen_file_path($id) 
{
   $key=md5($id);
   $fname='';
   for ($x=0; $x<=GEN_LEVELS; $x++) {
       $fname=substr($key, 0, 1) . "/";
       $key=substr($key,1);
   }  
   return GEN_BASE_PATH . "/" . $fname . $key; 
}
```

However the real way to solve the problem would be to serve the content with the right headers and run a caching reverse proxy in front of the webserver (though this isn't really practical for a very lwo volume site).

Comment: That is a great answer too but what Madara Uchiha said is easier for me :)